# Pentaho: Getting only one in row from JSON input file

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde, pentaho-data-integration

I am getting one JSON file from SFTP and trying it to insert into oracle but in the preview section i am getting only one row and only one row inserting into table. I already tried to modify to number to preview rows to 10000 but nothing working out.

{"postal_code":"XX","build_id":"XX","categories":[],"closed":false,"closed_reasons":[],"email":["XX"],"external_link":{"facebook":[],"yelp":[""]},"hq":false,"location":{"lat":xxxxx,"lon":xxxxx},"metro":"Cxxxxx, IL","naics_codes":[{"category_code":"XX","category_description":"XX"},{"category_code":"XX","category_description":"xxxxx "},{"category_code":"XX","category_description":"xxxxx "},{"category_code":xxxxx","category_description":"XX"}],"name":"XX","place_id":"XX","place_ids":["xxx","xx"],"sic_codes":[{"category_code":"XX","category_description":"XX"},{"category_code":"XX","category_description":"XX"}]}

Comment: On the `JSON Input` / `Field` tab, there is a `Repeat` column.

Comment: yes, i already marked it as "Yes"

Comment: Please provide a sample of json you’re getting.

Comment: I added in the description

Answer (score 0):

Your example json is:

```
{
"postal_code":"XX",
"build_id":"XX",
"categories":[],
"closed":false,
"closed_reasons":[],
"email":["XX"],
"external_link":{
    "facebook":[],
    "yelp":[""]
},
"hq":false,
"location":{
    "lat":xxxxx,
    "lon":xxxxx
},
"metro":"Cxxxxx, IL",
"naics_codes":[
    {
        "category_code":"XX",
        "category_description":"XX"
    },
    {
        "category_code":"XX",
        "category_description":"xxxxx "
    },
    {
        "category_code":"XX",
        "category_description":"xxxxx "
    },
    {
        "category_code":xxxxx",
        "category_description":"XX"
    }
],
"name":"XX",
"place_id":"XX",
"place_ids":["xxx","xx"],
"sic_codes":[
    {
        "category_code":"XX",
        "category_description":"XX"
    },
    {
        "category_code":"XX",
        "category_description":"XX"
    }
]
```

}

So, if that's the total values in the response you're getting from the SFTP server, Pentaho is behaving well, because it's only one record. If you want PDI to recognize the fields inside that json, and split it's content, you need to specify the path to each field on the "Path" field available on the "Fields" tab on the "Json Input" step.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the input json file as follows:

```
{
    "data" : [
                {"key":"val","key":"val"},
                {"key":"val","key":"val"},
                {"key":"val","key":"val"},
                {"id":"666","name":"jnit"}
            ]
}
```